# Linux choke on interface labels > 16 characters under Fedora 20+

Tags: fedora, udev, interface

I have an app that creates a subinterface (appending :ABCDE to the associated NIC label).  This worked fine when interfaces were labelled something like eth0 or eth1.  However, under Fedora 20 (and perhaps beyond) labels are 'eno16777736' for example (See below).  So appending :ABCDE to this label results in an interface label > 16 characters, which causes Linux to complain and refuse to create the subinterface.

```
root@localhost rules.d]# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno16777736: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:0f:32:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno33554984: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:0f:32:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

What is the solution here?  Can the max length of the interface labels be increased?  I can't imagine the kernel developers thought eno12345678 was a clever NIC label so I'm also wondering if something isn't set right on my system?

Comment: _interface names are limited to IFNAMSIZ characters, and that's defined to 16 on Linux (and can't realistically be changed), of which one must be the trailing 0_. see [`include/linux/if.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/if.h): `#define IFNAMSIZ        16`